# How to acess data coming from ng-controller for 'src' in <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below is the sample html come snip

```
<div data-ng-controller="sampleCtrl" >
<ul data-ng-repeat="item in sampleData">
    <li class="message">
        <img src="img-source" width="30" height="30">
        <div class="message-text">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="username">{{item.user}}</a> <h4>Number: {{item.num}}</h4>  {{item.msg}} 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here `sampleData` is a `json`. A variable in the `sampleData` contains `source` of the images. How to give this image source coming from the controller data as the `src` from `img` tag in Line 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if sampleData[x].source is the source of the image then

```
<img ng-src="{{item.source}}" width="30" height="30">
```

**edit:**

Use ng-src not src

Comment: Thank you so much. Before posting question itself, i tried to use `src`. And your edit to the answer saved me :)